# Removing the common elements between two lists

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python list subtraction operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/python-list-subtraction-operation)

I want to remove the common elements between two lists. I mean something like this

---

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b=[2,4,1]
# I want the result to be like
res=[3,5,6,7,8]
```

---

Is there any simple pythonic way to do this ?

Comment: What have you got till now?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

use sets :

```
res = list(set(a)^set(b))
```

Comment: You should note that this loses ordering and any duplicates in either list. If OP doesn't mind that, though, it's the sexiest solution.

Comment: Awesome! What's the `^` operand meaning in this case?

Comment: ^ here means disjoint.

Comment: keep in mind that results contains uncommon elements from b. for ex :
a = [1,2,3,4,5] and b = [1,2,8] the result is : [3,4,5,8]

Answer (score 12):

You can use sets learn more from [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

```
print(set(a).difference(b))
```

Comment: `list(set(a).difference(b))` make ordered list. What if i donot want ordered list and want same as list a, just removed common elements

Comment: may be `x = [i for i in x if i not in y] ` good choice.

Comment: This doesn't quite answer the OP as stated... but this DOES answer the question I was actually looking for, and is a useful answer. This returns only the elements of a that are not in b (OP asked for non-dupe elements in both a and b)