# removing common string elements in two sets python3

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, set

I am trying to figure out how to remove the common values in two sets.

```
set1={":dog","cat","mouse"}
set2={"bird","dog","house","fish"}
```

So the result is just `{"cat","mouse","bird","house","fish"}`.

I was looking on stack overflow and found this 
[Removing the common elements between two lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672543/removing-the-common-elements-between-two-lists)
but I'm not sure if it's specific to numbers or like the old python format because it wasn't working.

In my code I first got rid of the : in set1 by doing

```
line = re.sub('[:]', '', str(set1))
```

then I did :

```
res=list(set(line)^set(set2))
```

and I also tried

```
res=list(line^set2)
```

but the output is very strange it's

```
[',', 'u', 'c', '{', "'", 'o', 's', 'g', 'house', 'd', 't', 'bird', 'fish', 'm', 'dog', 'a', 'e', ' ', '}']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few way:

```
set1 = {":dog", "cat", "mouse"}
set2 = {"bird", "dog", "house", "fish"}

set1 = {k.replace(':', '') for k in set1}

# 3 equivalent methods

set1 ^ set2
set1.symmetric_difference(set2)
(set1 | set2) - (set1 & set2)

# {'bird', 'cat', 'fish', 'house', 'mouse'}
```

Comment: do you know why using regex like this caused an issue? line = re.sub('[:]', '', str(set1))

Comment: Look at what `str(set1)` does.. it coverts your set into a string: "{'cat', ':dog', 'mouse'}". You then apply some re logic, but then you have to convert the resulting string back to a set again. This is expensive and not what you want.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Comparing a string to a set does not work (in python or any other language).