# Python List out of index Pyschools Topic 6 q 21

Tags: python, list

I'm attempting to better myself at Python through pyschools exercises, but this one keeps getting me stumped. My logic makes perfect sense to me but somewhere it keeps throwing an out of bounds error on the list.

Here is the question

Write a function (list1, list2) that takes in two lists as arguments and return a list that is the result of removing elements from list1 that can be found in list2.

Examples

ubtractList

> > > subtractList(range(5), range(4))
> > >           [4]
> > >       subtractList([1,2,3,4,5], [2, 4])
> > >           [1, 3, 5]
> > >       subtractList (['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y', 'z'])
> > >           ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

Here is what I have so far

```
def subtractList(list1, list2): 
    if len(list1) > 0:
        for i in range(len(list1)):
            for p in range(len(list2)):
                if list1[i] == list2[p]:
                    list1.remove(list1[i])
    return list1
```

Comment: Not sure why do you need so many loops here.  1 would suffice.

Comment: Also, you could throw them into sets and do simple subtraction on the two lists. `set(l2)-set(l1)` or even better, a list comprehension like (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/python-list-subtraction-operation)

Comment: Perfect @limelights that's what I'm looking for. I'm attempting to learn the ins and outs of Python and this just helped a lot. I keep seeing it everywhere but never saw a name for it.

Comment: @limelights Technically, you'll need `list(set(l1) - set(l2))` in order to address the question exactly (return **list** of items from `l1` that are not in `l2`) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you want to learn, so for the moment I'll give you some hints. If thats not what you've expected, comment and I'll edit this post and provide a code snippet.

**I REPEAT** - before you downvote, ask for snippet in comment.

1. You can easily do this with [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/). That is really verbose, in this case will do, but for complicated conditions it may be too ugly.
2. See [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#filter) builtin function. Remember that it returns generator, so you probably want to pass this to `list()`

Hint: Your condition is "element not in list2". You can embed this in comprehension (in frist case) or wrap in `lambda` or named function (normal one, with `def`, etc) in second case.

Answer (score 0):

So, there are a lot of comments/answers as to methods to complete what you want, I am going to show you why you are getting the error you are with your code.

You are mutating `list1` here:

```
                list1.remove(list1[i])
```

At the same time, `range(len(list1))` from:

```
    for i in range(len(list1)):
```

Remains the same list, as in, it has the length of `list1` from the very beginning.