# print item(s) that do not exist in both list

Tags: python, list, loops, zip

```
row_names=['a','b','b','b']
col_names=['a','a','a','b','b','b']
```

How do I only print items that do not match in both? Zip doesnt work due to unequal lengths.

Something along this line?

```
 for item in row_names, col_names:
    if row_names[item] != col_names[item]:
        print item
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: zip-like function that pads to longest length?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/python-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length)

Comment: [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

Comment: `set(col_names) ^ set(row_names)`

Comment: And a direct answer for your problem [Python list subtraction operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/python-list-subtraction-operation)

Comment: @BhargavRao that only works for strings of unique values?

Comment: @Jenn Which, `izip_longest`? Nope. It works for everything. In your case you've gotta do `izip_longest(row_names,col_names,fillvalue = 0)` instead of `zip`

Comment: Brother @Jenn I understand your issue. Do go through both the links that I have added. If you still face a problem, please ping me back. I will be more than glad to help you out with an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `set.symmetric_difference`:

```
results = set(col_names).symmetric_difference(set(row_names))
# Or
results = set(col_names) ^ set(row_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
row_names=['a','b','b','b']
col_names=['a','a','a','b','b','b']

def diff(row,col):
    big, little = [row,col] if len(row) > len(col) else [col,row]
    map (lambda item: big.pop(big.index(item)) if item in big else None,little) 
    return big

print 'res: {}'.format(diff(row_names,col_names))
```

res: ['a', 'a']