# Exclude runs of the same element from itertools.product

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have the following code:

```
possible_keys = map(lambda combo: ''.join(combo), itertools.product(LETTERS, repeat=key_len))
```

It generates all the possible combinations in the alphabet based on the key length I'm passing it. For example, if I pass in 2, it will generate aa, ab, ac, and so on. If I pass in 3, it will generate aaa, aab, aac, and so on.

I would like to optimize my code a little better by removing instances where the string is all the same letters, e.g. aaa, bbbb, ccccccc. Essentially, removing the diagonals if this was a matrix. How can I accomplish that with this or if there a better way?

**EDIT**: I'm working on the Vigenere Cipher by dictionary attack. I didn't want to reveal big problem I was working on because I was afraid people would give answers to that instead haha. Though, now any suggestions welcomed :)  This is my first iteration of my program so it's really inefficient because I'm going through all possible keys and matching it with what's in the dictionary provided..

Comment: You could possibly use `len(set(x)) != 1`. Try this: `[i for i in possible_keys if len(set(i)) != 1]`

Comment: Could you provide more information about the problem? I mean, the real problem. This seems to be a solution for something inside another thing you want to do. If you tell us, we could give you a even better solution! :)
(read this for more info: http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Should `ab` and `ba` both be in the result?

Comment: @MikaelSouza Yeah for sure! I'll edit the question :)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yes

Comment: @heyyo Sorry if you didn't want to tell us the big problem. It is just that most people do this by accident. I hope we can help you without spoiling it! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the fact that the runs of the same element are located

> L<sup>0</sup>+L<sup>1</sup>+...+L<sup>L-1</sup>=(L<sup>L</sup>-1)/(L-1)

elements apart, and there are `L` of them in total, we can exclude them from the `product` at the end without encumbering the inner loop or computing hashes:

```
LETTERS='abc'
l = len(LETTERS)
p = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(LETTERS,repeat=l)]
step=(l**l-1)/(l-1)
for i in range(l):
    del p[i*step-i]    #allow for the fact that each time we delete an element,
                       #all indices shift backward by one
```

Comparative performance:

```
In [88]: letters=string.ascii_lowercase[:8]    # 8**8=16777216 elements in product

In [89]: timeit ex(letters)           # this solution
1 loop, best of 3: 6.1 s per loop  

In [90]: timeit minus_set(letters)    # subtracting a set at the end
1 loop, best of 3: 28.1 s per loop

In [92]: timeit ck_len(letters)       # checking len(set(i))
1 loop, best of 3: 15.1 s per loop

In [94]: timeit not_set(letters)      # checking `not in exclude'
1 loop, best of 3: 7.54 s per loop

def ex_mod_iter(letters):   # counter in the loop like it'd be done in C
    l = len(letters)
    step=(l**l-1)/(l-1)
    p = [''.join(v) for i,v in enumerate(itertools.product(letters,repeat=l)) if i % step]
    return p

In [5]: timeit ex_mod_iter(letters)
1 loop, best of 3: 6.61 s per loop
```

Comment: Nice! I thought about it theoretically (popping the indexes). But you made it possible. Most likely the fastest too (but not most readable I'd say).

Comment: @AntonvBR To my surprise, not everyone else is left in the dust :-)

Comment: Fastest indeed!! However my belief is that ppl don’t use Python for computation speed and in that case I’d vote for the exclude code for readabiity.

Comment: Filtering earlier: `p = [''.join(p) for (i, p) in enumerate(itertools.product(LETTERS,repeat=l)) if i % step]`

Comment: I realize that's similar to your `ex_mod_iter` except you composed `enumerate()` using `izip()` and `count()` and explicitly checked the mod as not equal zero.  I wonder if that impacted performance. (I'll check tomorrow when I'm at a computer.)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski thanks, I forgot that `enumerate()` returns an iterator, so it's safe to use for humongous sequences. Yes, the change reduced the time by about a second.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply check if the first letter occupies the entire string and exclude strings that match the criterion:

```
possible_keys = [''.join(x) for x in product(L, repeat=key_len) 
                                      if len(x) != x.count(x[0])]
```

Although `tuple.count` has the same O(n) complexity as `set()`, counting is relatively cheaper and thus likely to be **much faster** than building sets from the tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Using set (which can only hold unique values), we can do this e.g.:

```
import itertools
possible_keys = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('AB', repeat=2) if len(set(i)) !=1]
print(possible_keys)
```

Returns:

```
['AB', 'BA']
```

*Side note: lambda is not necessary here*

**For more speed:** 
we could also make an exception list first if speed is more important.

```
exclude = {(x,)*3 for x in 'ABC'}
possible_keys= [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('ABC', repeat=3) if i not in exclude]
```

---

**For [A-Z] you can use:**

```
import string
n = 4
letters = string.ascii_uppercase
exc = {(x,)*n for x in letters}
l = [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(letters, repeat=n) if i not in exc]
```

---

**timings**

```
%timeit l = {(x,)*3 for x in 'ABC'};[''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('ABC', repeat=3) if i not in l ]
%timeit [''.join(i) for i in itertools.product('ABC', repeat=3) if len(set(i)) !=1]
%timeit [''.join(x) for x in itertools.product('ABC', repeat=3) if len(x) != x.count(x[0])]

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.48 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.7 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 8.19 µs per loop
```

Comment: This has quadratic complexity.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: that is correct, but the problem is inherently quadratic, since if the charset contains 3 elements, there will be 6 elements, if it has 4, it will be 12, etc. Strictly speaking it has *n^k * k* complexity.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Hmm... it's cubic then? `set()` adds `N` additional steps at each iteration of `product`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: no it is exponential, but there is not much we can do about it, because the result set has that size, and you can not generate *n* items in a time complexity less than *O(n)*.

Comment: Your timing is **unfair**. Why have you neglected the time for building the `exclude` list for the first approach?

Comment: nice. I'm using A-Z in my implementation so either way it will take a long time ;)

Comment: @AntonvBR Quantitatively, there is no such thing as it builds fast. Include it and see what happens.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Done.

Comment: @AntonvBR Fair enough. However, you're using a generator expression which gets exhausted after the first membership check and just skips over the rest. Use a set comprehension instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how efficient this is but it should do the trick.

```
# Remove combos that are composed of the same letter.
possible_keys = map(lambda combo: ''.join(combo) if len(set(combo)) > 1 else False, itertools.product(LETTERS, repeat=key_len))
```

It also uses `set` but does the filtering in the lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

You can use the itertools.repeat to get a list of the sequences you wish to take out of your original list.

```
import itertools
import string

# get all sequences with all same letters
all_same_sequences = [''.join(list(itertools.repeat(char, key_len))) for char in string.ascii_lowercase]

# take those sequences out of the original list
possible_keys = sort(list(set(possible_keys ) - set(all_same_sequences)))
```

Comment: True, you can either use list(set(x) - set(y)) or to use the solution given here to make this work rather easily:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/python-list-subtraction-operation