# How do I subtract lists from each other?

Tags: python, list

I have two functions that output 2 lists respectively using what I've coded below. I'm trying to subtract one list from another.

```
def ok(n):
    results = []
    for n in range (2, n+1):
        s = Sup(n)
        results.append(s)
    return(results)


def uk(m):
    result = []
    for m in range (2, m+1):
        t = Sdown(m)
        result.append(t)
    return(result)
print(ok(7))
print(uk(7))

uk(7) - ok(7)
```

When I call, ok(7) I get:

```
[1.0833333333333333, 1.7178571428571427, 2.380728993228994, 3.05849519543652, 3.7438909037057684, 4.433147092589173]
```

Similarly for uk(7), I get:

```
[2.083333333333333, 2.7178571428571425, 3.380728993228993, 4.058495195436521, 4.743890903705768, 5.433147092589174]
```

I've tried then performing the operation: uk(7) - ok(7) but get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-3aa3eb52f7a8> in <module>
     18 print(uk(7))
     19 
---> 20 uk(7) - ok(7)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It's not something to _fix_. If you want element-wise operation, try: `[l1-l2 for l1,l2 in zip(uk(7), ok(7))]` or use `numpy`

Comment: To help you understand why Python is throwing an error here, notice it's not immediately obvious what the `-` operation should do to two lists. Maybe element-wise subtraction (subtract `a[0]` from `b[0]`, ...). But what if the lists are different lengths? What if one list is empty? You'll need to implement the behavior you're seeking yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list subtraction operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/python-list-subtraction-operation)

Comment: Unless OP was intending to emulate set difference by doing `uk(7) - ok(7)` (which is unlikely), the question is not a duplicate to [Python list subtraction operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/python-list-subtraction-operation).

Answer (score 2):

You Cannot subtract list from another list. Try using [numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.subtract.html) or Zip

```
>>> l1 = [1.0833333333333333, 1.7178571428571427, 2.380728993228994, 3.05849519543652, 3.7438909037057684, 4.433147092589173]
>>> l2 = [2.083333333333333, 2.7178571428571425, 3.380728993228993, 4.058495195436521, 4.743890903705768, 5.433147092589174]

>>> import numpy as n
>>> n.array(l2) - n.array(l1)
    array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair the elements of your lists, and a list comprehension to generate the output list:

```
difference = [u - o for u, o in zip(uk(7), ok(7))]
```

`zip` yields tuples by combining the elements of your two lists `uk(7)` and `ok(7)`:

- `(<first item of uk(7)>, first item of ok(7)>)`
- `(<second item of uk(7)>, second item of ok(7)>)`
- ...

In the for loop, the two values in the tuple are unpacked to `u` and `o`, and the `difference` list is built of the resulting `u - o` values.

Search about 'list comprehension' if you don't know about it, you'll find plenty of information.