# Remove common items from two lists (order is important!)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've searched all around the web but couldn't find the answer. 
There are two lists like this:

```py
A = [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]
B = [1,2,3]
```

I wanna get output like this:

```py
Out = [4,3,2,1]
```

First match of duplicate values will remove.
SUGGESTED LINK DIDN'T SOLVE MY PROBLEM. If I use that, output will be:

```py
Out =[4]
```

Comment: This example is not enough, what happens in case of `A=[1,2,3,1,4,3,2,1]` and `B=[1,2,1]`?

Comment: It would be [3,4,3,2,1] wanna delete first match. AND MY QUESTION ISN'T DUPLICATE

Comment: what happens in case of A = [1,2,1] and B = [1,2,3,1,4,3,2,1]

Comment: Does the order have to match? If `A = [1, 2, 3, 4]` does `B = [3, 2, 1]` behave differently from `B = [1, 2, 3]`?

Comment: @Darkknight: Unless there is some subtlety you haven't explained, your question is a duplicate; the linked duplicate also wants to be able to remove exactly one of each copy of a value in one `list` from another `list`. You just need to read more of the answers, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20259489/364696).

Comment: FYI, I did add [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57827145/364696) to [Python list subtraction operation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3428536/364696) that is order-preserving, cares about element counts, and is `O(m + n)` (rather than `O(m * n)` like the other order-preserving, count-sensitive answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the second list and remove the first one of each in B:

```
out = A[:]  # If you don't care about A being changed, this isn't needed

for b in B:
   out.remove(b)
```

Now out contains what you need. Remove() removes the first item that matches.

Comment: what if  A = [1,2,1] and B = [1,2,3,1,4,3,2,1]

Comment: That raises a ValueError, which doesn't seem unreasonable to me.

Comment: This does `O(m * n)` work (`m` being length of `B`, `n` length of `A`), which is sub-optimal; for large inputs, building a new output by converting `B` to something like `collections.Counter`, then making a new `list` from `A` by `append`ing to the new `list` only if the count for the value is 0, otherwise decrementing the count, would reduce the work to `O(m + n)`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: but isn't appending to a list linear, so that that would be quadratic if all elements of A are appended one by one?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: It's amortized `O(1)`; some appends require a resize, but it overallocates by a multiple of the current size, so most do not require a resize, they just put the pointer in an existing slot and increment the logical length.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich: I posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57827145/364696) that demonstrates the approach I described in detail, with explanation if you want to check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [1,2,1]
B = [1,2,3,1,4,3,2,1]
for b in B:
    if b in A:
        A.remove(b)
        B.remove(b)
print(A+B)
```

This is waht I suggest!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Out = list(set(A)^set(B))
```

Full solution:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,3,2,1]
B = [1,2,3]
Out = list(set(A)^set(B))
print (Out)
```

To print in sorted order:

```
print (sorted(Out))
```

OR

```
print (list(set(A).difference(B)))
```

Comment: This will return only 4. 'cause if an object repeats in a set, it doesn't make diffrance. Than {4}=={4,4,4,4,4}.

Comment: I asked this question myself :) you mean I don't know what I asked? :)

Comment: Even if this were correct, `list(set(A)^set(B))` doesn't do the right thing when `B` contains elements not found in `A`; the result will *add* those `B`-only elements. You wanted `set(A) - set(B)`, not `set(A) ^ set(B)`.

Comment: It is about removing duplicate values and this does that perfectly!