# filter based on set membership

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would *love*

```
small_evens = set([2, 4, 6, 8])
only_small_odds = filter(not in small_evens, [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 7, 6, 4, 5])
```

but of course this is a syntax error.

both `filter(lambda x: x not in set, items)` and `[x for x in items if x not in set]` feel too verbose.

Is there another way?

I suspect there might be because, for example, newer Python versions have made `map(str.lower, strings)` possible (used to have to `map(lambda s: s.lower(), strings)`)

Comment: Why use `filter`? Since you're already working with sets, why not: `set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) - set([2, 4, 6, 8])`

Comment: @PaulM. the second argument is not a set

Comment: 'x and y feel to verbose' is opinion based. Both are pythonic solutions to your question.

Comment: `itertools.filterfalse(small_evens.__contains__, items)`

Answer (score 0):

You could write a function:

```
def not_in(it):
    def inner(x):
        return x not in it
    return inner

only_small_odds = filter(not_in(small_evens), [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 7, 6, 4, 5])
```

But the 'verbose' ways you don't like are more pythonic.

You could also subclass list to make a [subtractable list class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3428637/567595), and then do:

```
only_small_odds = SubtractableList([1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 7, 6, 4, 5]) - small_evens
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, which is pretty close:

```
from itertools import filterfalse

only_small_odds = filterfalse(small_evens.__contains__, [1, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 7, 6, 4, 5])
```